# np.random.choice with a big probabilities array

Tags: python, numpy, random

I know that we can use a probability array for the choice function, but my question is how it works for big arrays. Let's assume that I want to have 1 thousand random numbers between 0-65535. How can we define the probability array to have p=0.4 for numbers less than 1000 and p=0.6 for the rest?

I tried to pass the range of numbers to the choice function, but apparently, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: `p=0.4` across _all_ numbers less than 1000, right?

Comment: yes, [0, 999] with p = 0.4 and [1000, 65535] with p = 0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be to treat this as a [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of two distributions: one that draws uniformly from {0..999} with probability = 0.4, and another that draws uniformly from {1000..65535} with probability = 0.6.

Using `choice` for the mixture component makes sense, but then I'd use something else to draw the values because when probabilities are passed to `choice` it does O(`len(p)`) work every call to transform them.  [`Generator.integers`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.integers.html) should be more efficient as it can sample your uniform values directly.

Putting this together, I'd suggest using something like:

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

n = 1000
splits = np.array([0, 1000, 65536])

# draw weighted mixture components
s = rng.choice(2, n, p=[0.4, 0.6])
# draw uniform values according to component
result = rng.integers(splits[s], splits[s+1])
```

You can verify this is drawing from the correct distribution by evaluating `np.mean(result < 1000)` and checking it's "close" to 0.4.  The [variance of that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) is approximately `0.4*0.6 / n`, so, for `n=1000`, values in [0.37, 0.43] should be seen 95% of the time.

This method should remain fast while `max(splits) - min(splits)` gets larger, while Pranav's solution of using `choice` directly will slow down.

Comment: This is a great approach! It took me a while to time your approach vs. mine. I've edited my answer to include a runtime comparison, and using `Generator.integers` wins easily for the larger inputs

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), each element of the argument `p` gives the probability for the *corresponding element* in `a`.

Since `p` and `a` need to have the same size, create a `p` of the same size as `a`:

```
a = np.arange(65536)
n_elem = len(a)

p = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=float)
```

Now, find all the elements of `a` less than `1000`, and set `p` for those indices to 0.4 divided by the number of elements less than 1000. For this case, you can hardcode that calculation, since you know which elements of an `arange` are less than 1000:

```
p[:1000] = 0.4 / 1000
p[1000:] = 0.6 / 64536
```

For the general case where `a` is not derived from an `arange`, you could do:

```
lt1k = a < 1000
n_lt1k = lt1k.sum()

p[lt1k] = 0.4 / n_lt1k
p[~lt1k] = 0.6 / (n_elem - n_lt1k)
```

Note that `p` must sum to `1`:

```
assert np.allclose(p.sum(), 1.0)
```

Now use `a` and `p` in `choice`:

```
selection = np.random.choice(a, size=(1000,), p=p)
```

To verify that the probability of selecting a value < 1000 is 40%, we can check how many are less than 1000:

```
print((selection < 1000).sum() / len(selection)) # should print a number close to 0.4
```

---

I compared runtimes between the approach Sam suggested in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75138908/843953) vs. mine. Results are plotted below for `splits = np.array([0, N//2, N])` for increasing `N`. While using `random.choice` directly is faster for `max(splits) - min(splits) < ~5k`, Sam's approach beats mine *handily* for the larger inputs.

[image]

My timing code is below if you're interested:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def time_funcs(funcs, sizes, arg_gen, N=20):
    times = np.zeros((len(sizes), len(funcs)))
    gdict = globals().copy()
    for i, s in enumerate(sizes):
        args = arg_gen(s)
        print(args)
        for j, f in enumerate(funcs):
            gdict.update(locals())
            try:
                times[i, j] = timeit.timeit("f(*args)", globals=gdict, number=N) / N
                print(f"{i}/{len(sizes)}, {j}/{len(funcs)}, {times[i, j]}")
            except ValueError:
                print("ERROR in {f}({*args})")
                
            
    return times

def plot_times(times, funcs):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for j, f in enumerate(funcs):
        ax.plot(sizes, times[:, j], label=f.__name__)
    
    
    ax.set_xlabel("Array size")
    ax.set_ylabel("Time per function call (s)")
    ax.set_xscale("log")
    ax.set_yscale("log")
    ax.legend()
    ax.grid()
    fig.tight_layout()
    return fig, ax

#%%
def arg_gen(n):
    return [np.array([0, n//2, n]), np.array([0.4, 0.6]), n//2]

#%%
def mixture(splits, probs, n):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    # draw weighted mixture components
    s = rng.choice(2, n, p=probs)
    # draw uniform values according to component
    return rng.integers(splits[s], splits[s+1])

def choices(splits, probs, n):
    a = np.arange(splits[0], splits[-1])
    n_elem = len(a)
    p = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=float)
    lt1k = a < splits[1]
    n_lt1k = lt1k.sum()
    
    p[lt1k] = probs[0] / n_lt1k
    p[~lt1k] = probs[1] / (n_elem - n_lt1k)
    
    return np.random.choice(a, size=(n,), p=p)

def choices_hc(splits, probs, n):
    assert splits[0] == 0
    a = np.arange(splits[-1])
    p = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=float)
    p[:splits[1]] = probs[0] / splits[1]
    p[splits[1]:] = probs[1] / (splits[2] - splits[1])
    return np.random.choice(a, size=(n,), p=p)
    
#%% 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #%% Set up sim
    # sizes = [5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10_000, 50_000, 100_000]
    sizes = [5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10_000, 50_000, 100_000, 1_000_000, 5_000_000, 10_000_000]
    funcs = [mixture, choices, choices_hc]
    
    
    #%% Run timing
    time_fcalls = np.zeros((len(sizes), len(funcs))) * np.nan
    time_fcalls = time_funcs(funcs, sizes, arg_gen)
    
    fig, ax = plot_times(time_fcalls, funcs)
    # ax.set_xlabel(f"Input size")
    ax.set_xlabel(f"max(splits) - min(splits)")

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Nice benchmarking!  Wasn't sure where the crossover would be, just assumed it would be somewhere...  I think I'd put the rng creation outside the method, but otherwise looks good.